# Angular self invoking function

Tags: angularjs

I see many people using self invoking functions as a wrapper for angular modules e.g.

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('directivesModule');

  app.directive('domDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

          }
      };
  });

}());
```

Is there any advantage of wrapping  like this? Or it is just a matter of coding style?

Thank you!

Comment: read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/2435473 would help you..

Comment: It's an [iife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), but it also helps prevent against polluting the global scope unnecessarily.